# MySql trigger, identify direct database access

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on one table. Now in that trigger, I want to identify whether the update query is sent from application (Java) or it is direct from database access, like a query from MySql command prompt.

Is it possible in MySql trigger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Triggers are fired independent of clients. They are not built for client specific concerns.
And hence you can't find which client's statement caused the trigger to fire.